# Fastest Way to copy/transfer Tera bytes of data between SQL Database Servers

Tags: sql-server, performance, server, data-transfer, bigdata

I am looking for a most efficient and fastest way to transfer huge data from a SQL Server located in Europe to SQL Server located in USA.

The traditional ways are taking longer time.

1. Linked Server
2. SQL bulk copy or BCP
3. SQL database replication
4. SQL Import Wizard

Cloud is an option but it comes with data privacy issues. I am not looking for offline copy using backup and restore or transfer via hard disc.

Can anyone suggest the best way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: [Sneakernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet) is an option, especially If you have people traveling anyway.

Comment: This is most likely a network bandwidth issue, not a "copy technique" issue.  Analyze your network's capacity and use that to calculate the fastest possible copy time you could achieve.  How close are you current times to that ideal time?  If they are pretty close, then there's probably not much you can do.

Comment: This is not just a bandwidth issue, especially if trying to use TCP-based protocols such as FTP, SCP, or HTTP[S].  TCP performs poorly across high-latency connections even with huge bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the company from Europe to back everything up in a HD and ship it securely. My work does it this way. Shipping Oracle DB copies from LA

Comment: According to [this article](https://phys.org/news/2009-09-carrier-pigeon-faster-broadband-internet.html) a pigeon with a usb stick can out speed a broadband connection.  (A humorous hyperbole reinforcing your point)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not looking for offline transfers. But this was a good idea if some one is fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative 1: using compressed full backup file  of the database**

- Full backup the database
- Compress the backup file and splitting it into smaller chunks of size 500MB  (or less) using zip tool.

note: You can back up to multiple files with compression that save about 60%– in one or more locations using SSMS or T-Sql script – and multiple threads will be used.
 This can make a backup take less time and no need to use zip tool.

- Host the files in ftp server or http uploader server
- Copy the data files from the source http/ftp using http /ftp protocol
- In the target server uncompress the files and compose one backup file
- Restore the database

**Update:**

**Alternative 2: Using compressed bcp files**

- SQL bulk copy or BCP out  as native data
- compress the files using zip
- host files in ftp server or http uploader server
- Copy files from the source http/ftp using  http /ftp protocol
- in the target server uncompress the files
- bcp in from data files

  **note:**

  - You can use batch file or Powershell scripts to automate these tasks
  - Speed of network is controlled by network speed of the service provider, contact your internet service provider to get the max speed.
  - We avoided the online interaction between source/target Sql servers to avoid the time out of the network.